# How to set transparent drawer in react native 6.x

Tags: react-native

How to set transparent drawer in react native 6.x

backgroundColor:"transparent" didn't work
overlay:"transparent" didn't work
drawerBackgroundColor:"transparent" didn't work
So How to set transparent drawer in react native 6.x?

Comment: Similar issue is discussed in [https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9834](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9834).

Answer (score 0):

### Use rgba value for the backgroundColor.

example

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.8)'
```

This sets it to a grey color with 80% opacity, This value can be anything from 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: it's not change the background like transparent